# after run , how to remove "" in the run screen?

Tags: python

```
Student1 = [10002726,'Gates William ','Graded']

Student2 = ["10002345","Tanaka","Teddy","Graded"]

Student3 = ["10006789","Jonea","Bridget","Pass/No Pass"]

Student4 = ["10011111","Ramirez","Serena","Graded"]

Student5 = ["10002323","Hanks","Tim","Graded"]

Student6 = ["10003738","Perez","Cecelia","Graded"]

Student7 = ["10002222","Bok","Sisely","Graded"]

Student8 = ["10009856","Whitcomb","Witney","Graded"]

Student9 = ["10008888","Chen","Sam","Pass/No Pass"]

Student10 = ["10003562","Bok","Sisely","Graded"]


print(Student1)

print(Student2)

print(Student3)

print(Student4)

print(Student5)

print(Student6)

print(Student7)

print(Student8)

print(Student9)

print(Student10)
```

After run, how to remove `""` in the run screen?

Comment: Can you please be more specific. Quotes around what exactly? All the elements in the array? Or just the number? You need to provide more detail here. This isn't very clear.

Comment: [10002726, 'Gates William Graded']
['10002345', 'Tanaka', 'Teddy', 'Graded']
['10006789', 'Jonea', 'Bridget', 'Pass/No Pass']
['10011111', 'Ramirez', 'Serena', 'Graded']
['10002323', 'Hanks', 'Tim', 'Graded']
['10003738', 'Perez', 'Cecelia', 'Graded']
['10002222', 'Bok', 'Sisely', 'Graded']
['10009856', 'Whitcomb', 'Witney', 'Graded']
['10008888', 'Chen', 'Sam', 'Pass/No Pass']
['10003562', 'Bok', 'Sisely', 'Graded']  this is the run one ,  can i take off ' ' this symobl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print(''.join(Student1).strip('"'))
```

Comment: If this is what you were looking for after all, you might actually want `' '.join(Student1)`. Note the space for the `join`. As is that solution will not have any spaces between the data you probably want spaced out. And you are creating a string already, so the `strip` is completely useless here.

Comment: can you tell me a little bit of strip ? I got confused

Comment: THANKS FOR EXPLAIN